# Why do I have EN-US CultureUiInfo where everything set to UK?

Tags: c#, windows-7, .net-4.5

My dev machine is W7 64. In **Region and Languages** I have:

- Format           : English (United Kingdom)
- Current Location : United Kingdom
- Default input language : English (United Kingdom)

However when I query Thread.CurrentThread ..

CultureInfo is en-GB and CultureUiInfo is en-US

**where the US comes from??**

Comment: Some clues might be found here: [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx). Namely: what's `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`? If it's null, what `GetUserDefaultUILanguage` returns?

Comment: default is null and Get returns en-US. Obviously problem is not in the .NET but in my PC settings. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to [`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this property defaults to the culture of the display language of your operating system which presumably is `en-US`.

Depending on your version and edition of Windows you can install [additional language packs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs) and/or reinstall another language version of Windows to change the display language.

However, as far as I know there does not exist a specific British English version of Windows.

Comment: This must be it. Also note that `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` are always the same (if you change the thread one one, the other will also change)

Comment: I wrote all the settings from the Region and Languages in the question (the bullet list).. What is "display language" you are referring to ? in terms of OS settings? thanks. ALSO you guys are wrong. Because when my code outputs dates using standard formatting it writes in US format. Obviously this is wrong. It never happened to me before and I am sure thousands of british devs would already complained everythere... which is not the case.. it is something wrong with this particular install of the W7

Comment: The [Windows display language](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+display+language) is _"the language Windows uses in wizards, dialog boxes, menus, and other items in the user interface"_. I have already explained how to change this language by either installing additional language packs or by reinstalling a different language version of Windows (depending on which Windows you have). `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` defaults to the culture you specify in Regional Settings (the _"Format"_). This is also the culture .NET uses to format dates if you do not specify a culture.

Comment: Regional Settings does not exist in W7. There is Region and Language. All the settings of the said feature already described on the very top of my questions and they *ALL ARE UK*.... Question was where US came from... ok? thanks.

Comment: @BoppityBop: In English Windows 7: Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards and Languages -> Install/uninstall languages -> Install display languages, but as I said, I do not believe there exists a specific en-GB version. When you switch the display language the default value of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` changes to match the display language and apparently when you have an English version of Windows the `CultureInfo` used is `en-US`.

Comment: Ok now I on the same page with you.. Please change "display language" in your answer to say "installed language" (because this created confusion in first place - display language is not the same 'language' you were talking about and it is UK English)

Comment: @BoppityBop: The Microsoft term is "display language" (which you can [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+display+language)), and that is also the text used in the English version of Windows.